# Cannot find audio file in google bucket with google speech API

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-speech-api

With the Google Speech API (using the python sample code), you need to have your audio files on google cloud when longer than 1 minute. According to some sample code, you can use a path like 
`gs://python-docs-samples-tests/speech/audio.flac`.

So I put my audio files in a `bucket`, and use (I believe) the correct path (i.e. `gs://bucket-name/foldername/myaudiofile.wav`), yet I get an error .

```
NotFound: 404 No such object: bucket-name/foldername/myaudiofile.wav
```

Even if I put the permission on public (which I rather not do), it cannot find the file. I have the feeling I am forgetting something very trivial here... But still haven't found it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the cloud console > select the project > go to Storage > Browse the buckets and make sure the file is actually there. Best way you can tell, IMO.